# Generate different combinations of arrays using positive integers as elements

Tags: arrays, ruby

Given a certain integer `n` and a different integer `k` (both positive) I want to generate all the possible different arrays of size `k` containing integers in the interval `[0..n]`. For example with `n = 2` and `k = 2` I want to generate an array of arrays that contains `[0,0]`, `[0,1]`, `[1,0]`, `[0,2]`, `[1,1]`, `[2,0]`, `[1,2]`, `[2,1]`, `[2,2]`. So the result should be

```
result = [[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [0,2], [1,1], [2,0], [1,2], [2,1], [2,2]]
```

The order of the elements doesn't matter.

Comment: yes, I forgot some of the combinations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array#repeated_permutation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-repeated_permutation):

```
(0..2).to_a.repeated_permutation(2).to_a
# => [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
arr = [*0..2]
arr.product(arr)
  #=> [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
```

If you just want an array, that's fine, but `Array#repeated_permutation`, because it returns an enumerator (rather than an array), would likely be more efficient if you want to chain another method to the result, such as one from the module `Enumerable` or class `Enumerator`.